# How to keep access token for subsequent requests in website like in mobile app

Tags: codeigniter, api, restful-authentication, stateless

I am developing a web api which will server mobile app and website, if as user access login service in api, user get validated and return back with access token, this access token will be stored in mobile and this access token will be used in subsequest requests for the resources in the api this is fine, but how can we store this access token in website(web browser) to use it for subsequest requests, shall we use sessions to store this access token, if so what about statelessness, if we store it in cokies it will be security treat right, please help me guys thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to store the access token in the browser's local storage.

**Syntax to add**

```
localStorage.setItem("appToken", token);
```

*where token is the value returned after successful authentication and appToken is the local variable holding that value.

**Syntax to access token variable**

```
var token = localStorage.appToken;
```

*you can access the same token in different pages so that you can hit APIs from there.

**Syntax to remove the token**

```
localStorage.removeItem("appToken");
```

*it's better to remove the token from appToken variable if you want to logout from the application.

Comment: Hi Aashu, First of all thank you for your reply, i understood what you are saying, but my question is saving appToken in browser storage will be a treat, it will be easily accessible, storing in browser will not be a treate storing in session variable is violating statelessness, this is where i stuck

Comment: if you want to develop generic APIs which will be used for both mobile apps and website then i suggest you not to store token in session variable, localStorage works great with cross platform applications but be sure that you use https protocol for the APIs. if you don't have SSL certificates you can get one free from letsencrypt.